# cordova build android error org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

Tags: android, ionic-framework, build

I get this error when i set cordova build android

> Erreur : impossible de trouver ou charger la classe principale org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Step 1. Download the [latest Gradle distribution](https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.0.2-bin.zip)
- Step 2. Create a new directory `C:\Gradle`
- Step 3. Unpack the Gradle distribution ZIP into `C:\Gradle` using an archiver tool of your choice.
- Step 3. Configure your system environment.
- In `File Explorer` right-click on the `This PC` (or Computer) icon, then click `Properties` -> `Advanced System Settings` -> `Environmental Variables`.

  Under `System Variables` select `Path`, then click `Edit`. Add an entry for `C:\Gradle\gradle-4.0.2\bin`. Click OK to save.
- Step 4. Verify your installation. Open a console (or a Windows command prompt) and run `gradle -v`